# Stubbing route callback render route status not found

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, chai-http

I have a route

```
app.get("/test", myControllers.controllerTest)
```

The controllerTest returns current time as result to query

my route test file

```
  describe.("GET /test", () => {
    it("should return correct response", done => {

      sinon.stub(myControllers, "controllerTest").yields(null, {time:'fake-time'});

      app = require("../../server");

      chai
        .request(app)
        .get("/test")
        .then(res => {
          expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
          expect(myControllers.controllerTest).to.have.been.calledOnce;
          done();
        })
        .catch(err=>{
          done(err)
        });
    });
  });
```

The test fails at it tells me route returned 404 instead of 200 after I stub the callback.

note that using `spy` instead of `stub` works. But in this case, i need to use `stub`

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

When stubbing the callback, I get error `cannot get /route`, It's  like the callback doesnt exist. it's same as executing `app.get('/test')`

Anyone have any idea how to stub the callback?